# What happens if a std::thread variable goes out of scope

Tags: c++, stdthread

Considering this piece of code:

```
#include <thread>

void foo()
{
  std::thread mythread(
    [=](int x)
    {
      // do some lengthy processing
      // ...
    }, 0);

  mythread.detach();
}

int main()
{
  while (true)
  {
    foo();
    // do more stuff
  }
}
```

In `foo` the local `mythread` goes out of scope once the `foo` function is finished.

Is the call to `std::detach` sufficient or can there still be problems if the destructor of `mythread` is called (which is obviously the case here at the end of `foo`). IOW is calling the destructor of a `std::thread` variable that has been detached with `std::thread::detach` a problem when the thread is still running (which is obviously the case in the code snippet)?.

The code itself is pretty pointless, it's only purpose is to illustrate the question.

Comment: "is the call to std::detach sufficient" sufficient for what? detaching a thread is very rarely the right thing to do

Comment: when an object with automatic storage duration goes out of scope, its destructor is called: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread

Comment: This should be sufficient: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach 

Also note that postcondition is `joinable == false` and here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread  you see that if `joinable == true` then `std::terminate` is called, otherwise not.

Comment: @odyss-jii question clarified. But anyway https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread explains it well enough for me. Answer to the question: No problem with this code. Key phrase in this link: "_A thread object does not have an associated thread (**and is safe to destroy**) after detach() has been called_".